# Is there a more efficient way to write this SQL Query to remove the distinct?

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

I'm trying to select items from table A where the equivalent items in table B exist for a given constraint. There is one row per id in table A but many rows per table A row.

```
select distinct A.id 
from A inner join B on B.a_id = A.id 
where B.x >= 5 and B.x <= 10;
```

I wonder if there's a SQL join clause that I can use to ensure that I only get one row per table A row.

As I understand it, the query will find the constraint, perform an inner join and then perform distinct on this. If this is correct, and there's a better way to instruct the database to only take distinct rows from A, I'd like to know. I'm sure there are plenty of ways that the query could be interpreted and executed within the constraints of the semantics of the query. I can't claim to understand the `explain` output.

Is there a way to simplify this? I'm constrained to SQLite if that makes any difference.

**EDIT**

The constraint clause has two constraints, defined at query-time which I have now added. I tried to keep the question as simple as possible, but have added the extra clause for completeness in response to a comment.

Comment: Can you clarify further, is this query not returning what you want?

Comment: The query is working fine. But wonder if it can be more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way to write the query:

```
select A.id
from A
where A.id in (select B.a_id from B where B.x > 5)
```

I don't think the performance will be any better, but it does eliminate the outer "distinct".

There is another version that I would use in MySQL:

```
select A.id
from A
where exists (select 1 from B where b.x > 5 and b.a_id = a.id limit 1)
```

This is potentially more efficient, because the query can use an index lookup and stop at the first match.  This is particularly true if you have an index on B for (a_id, x).

Comment: If he's using sqlite, why would you show something that you only will use in mysql?

Comment: @ElVieejo . . . The MySQL version is standard SQL and should also work in SQLite.  I happen to know that it optimizes well in MySQL.  I don't know whether or not SQLite optimizes this construct as efficiently.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff. For my data at least, your first suggestion is very slightly slower.

Comment: And I can confirm that both work in SQLite. I'll go away and run it on some large data and see what's best. Thanks for giving me some options!

Answer (score 1):

If there is a (properly enforced) `FOREIGN KEY` between the 2 tables, you will have a (slight) efficiency gain by eliminating table `A`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a_id AS id
FROM B 
WHERE x >= 5 and x <= 10 ;
```

An index on `(a_id, x)` seems appropriate but efficency will depend on various parameters (what percent of ids match the condition `x>5`? how many rows with same id?, etc).

I would also try this query (after adding the above index):

```
SELECT a_id AS id
FROM B 
GROUP BY a_id
HAVING MAX(x) >= 5 
   AND MIN(x) <= 10 ;
```

This will work when you want data from `A` as well:

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM A
  JOIN 
    ( SELECT a_id
      FROM B 
      GROUP BY a_id
      HAVING MAX(x) >= 5 
         AND MIN(x) <= 10  
    ) AS b
  ON b.a_id = a.id ;
```

Comment: It's so obvious! Thanks, that will eliminate one case. I am actually using other values from table A, but I do have one query that only uses IDs.

Comment: And please, do test all the possible variations, with tables or variable size, before you decide.

Comment: Argh no don't use that `> 5`! That's only an example constraint, I'm actually testing for a range of numbers which will be decided at query-time.

Comment: If your queries have  (example): `WHERE x IN (5, 17, 23, 456)`, why did you put something else in the question? Different queries often have different optimizations.

Comment: It's more like `b.x >= 5 and b.x <= 6`. I was trying to keep the question simple, as I didn't think any optimisations would focus on that bit of the query.

Comment: OK then. That is similar enough. Range conditions are often hard to optimize (Although they seem simple).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16512/discussion-between-ypercube-and-joe)